# Currency Converter using a picker and a dynamic collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

**HomePage XAML:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BankingApp.HomePage"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:BankingApp.Resources"
             Title="HomePage"
             BackgroundColor="#041014"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">

    <ScrollView>

        <VerticalStackLayout>
            
 
            <!--Logo-->
            <Image Source="logo.png" Margin="0,30,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="100"></Image>
            <Label FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.Title}" FontFamily="AgeoBold"></Label>
            <Label FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="10%"></Label>
            
            <!--Currency Picker-->

            <Picker x:Name="CurrencyInUse" Margin="0,0,20,0" FontSize="16" Title="Choose your Currency" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Euro</x:String>
                        <x:String>Dollar</x:String>
                        <x:String>Croatian Kuna</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>

            <Frame Margin="10" BackgroundColor="#16181C" HasShadow="True" Padding="20" CornerRadius="20">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="AgeoBold" TextColor="White" 
                       FontSize="18" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.InitialInvestment}"/>

                    <Grid Margin="0.5">
                        <Frame  Margin="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#202327" WidthRequest="150"  CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" >
                            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="IncomeInput" BackgroundColor="#202327"  TextColor="#0d1a21"  
                              FontFamily="OpenSansRegular" FontSize="16" Placeholder="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.HowMuch}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  PlaceholderColor="#202327" />
                        </Frame>

                    </Grid>

                    <Label  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="AgeoBold" TextColor="White" 
                       FontSize="18" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.Duration}"/>
                    <Grid Margin="0.5">
                        <Frame Opacity="1" Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#202327" WidthRequest="150"  CornerRadius="30" Padding="0" >
                            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" x:Name="MonthInput" BackgroundColor="#202327"  TextColor="#0d1a21"  
                              FontFamily="OpenSansRegular" FontSize="16" Placeholder="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.HowLong}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  PlaceholderColor="#202327"/>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>

                    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#00B2FF"
                    Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.Calculate}" TextColor="White" FontFamily="AgeoBold" Clicked="Calculate"/>

                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <Label FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.Results}" FontFamily="AgeoBold"></Label>

            <!--Tabela Savings Calculator-->
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10"  BackgroundColor="#202327" Padding="10">

                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.Month}"
                           FontFamily="AgeoBold" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{Binding Month}"  
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />

                            <Label Grid.Column="2"
                           Text="{x:Static res:LanguageResources.IncomewithRate}"
                           FontFamily="AgeoBold" />

                            <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Text="{Binding OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged}"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>



            <!--Final Página-->
        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

**HomePage C# :**

```
namespace BankingApp;
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };
    }

    //Calculadora de Conta Poupança
    public class MonthlyIncome
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public double Income { get; set; }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome> MonthlyIncomeCalculus { get; set; } = new();
    private void Calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext = MonthlyIncomeCalculus;
        MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Clear();

        MonthlyIncome monthi;
        int Months = int.Parse(MonthInput.Text);
        int Income = int.Parse(IncomeInput.Text);
        double Accumulated = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= Months; i++)
        {

            monthi = new MonthlyIncome();
            monthi.Month = i;

            //Input Validation (Inputs are empty)
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MonthInput.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(IncomeInput.Text))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input values!", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //Input Validation (Min/Max of Months)
            if (Months > 12 || Months < 1)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input value of range 1-12", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //Input Validation (Min of Investment)
            if (Income < 10)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input minimum value of 10", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //1ºMês - Meses Seguintes
            if (i == 1)
            {
                monthi.Income = (Income) * 1.10;
                Accumulated = (monthi.Income);
            }
            else if (i <= Months)
            {
                monthi.Income = Accumulated * 1.10;
                Accumulated = (monthi.Income);
            }
            //Arredondamento
            monthi.Income = Math.Round(monthi.Income, 2);

            //Currency Converter
            void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var picker = (Picker)sender;
                int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

                if (selectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    monthi.Income = monthi.Income;
                }
                if (selectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    monthi.Income /= 1.05;
                }

                if (selectedIndex == 3)
                {
                    monthi.Income /= 7.55;
                }
            }

            //Próximo Mês
            MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Add(monthi);
        }

    }

}
```

**What am I trying to do?**

I am trying to make a Currency Converter using a Picker and a Dynamic Collection View.

**More specifically...**

Current objective is that the user chooses a currency (dollars for example), inputs and gets the values in the Collection View. If the user wishes to see the values in Euros, the user changes the currency and the values are updated.

**What's the problem?**

I have tried setting the `monthi.Income` to appear in the collection view according to the `OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged`however when I calculate, no values appear. The code in its present form also presents no errors that stop the application.

Comment: first, you can only bind to **public properties**.  `OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged` is a **private method**.  Second, this would be an ideal use for an `IValueConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you are not using event `OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged`  for `Picker` correctly.

You can try to correct your code by following steps:

1.add event `SelectedIndexChanged` for the Picker in your xaml as follows:

```
        <Picker x:Name="CurrencyInUse" 
                SelectedIndexChanged="OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged"
                
                Margin="0,0,20,0" FontSize="16" Title="Choose your Currency" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Euro</x:String>
                    <x:String>Dollar</x:String>
                    <x:String>Croatian Kuna</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
```

2.remove text bind `OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged` for `Label`:

```
       <!--  remove code `Text="{Binding OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged}"`  -->

       <Label Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="{Binding OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

3.if you want to get the selected index of Picker, you can define a global variable as follows:

```
   public partial class HomePage : ContentPage 
{
    // define a global variable
    int selectedIndex = 0;

    public HomePage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };
    }
     // other codes
 }
```

4.the whole code is as follows:

```
  public partial class HomePage : ContentPage 
{
    // define a global variable
    int selectedIndex = 0;

    public HomePage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ = new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric };
    }

    //Calculadora de Conta Poupança
    public class MonthlyIncome
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public double Income { get; set; }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<MonthlyIncome> MonthlyIncomeCalculus { get; set; } = new();
    private void Calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext = MonthlyIncomeCalculus;
        MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Clear();

        MonthlyIncome monthi;   // jessie
        int Months = int.Parse(MonthInput.Text);
        int Income = int.Parse(IncomeInput.Text);
        double Accumulated = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= Months; i++)
        {

            monthi = new MonthlyIncome();
            monthi.Month = i;

            //Input Validation (Inputs are empty)
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MonthInput.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(IncomeInput.Text))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input values!", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //Input Validation (Min/Max of Months)
            if (Months > 12 || Months < 1)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input value of range 1-12", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //Input Validation (Min of Investment)
            if (Income < 10)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Attention", "Please input minimum value of 10", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            //1ºMês - Meses Seguintes
            if (i == 1)
            {
                monthi.Income = (Income) * 1.10;
                Accumulated = (monthi.Income);
            }
            else if (i <= Months)
            {
                monthi.Income = Accumulated * 1.10;
                Accumulated = (monthi.Income);
            }
            //Arredondamento
            monthi.Income = Math.Round(monthi.Income, 2);


            if (selectedIndex == 1)
            {
                monthi.Income = monthi.Income;
            }
            if (selectedIndex == 2)
            {
                monthi.Income /= 1.05;
            }

            if (selectedIndex == 3)
            {
                monthi.Income /= 7.55;
            }


            // remove code here
            //Currency Converter
            //void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //{
            //    var picker = (Picker)sender;
            //    int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

            //    if (selectedIndex == 1)
            //    {
            //        monthi.Income = monthi.Income;
            //    }
            //    if (selectedIndex == 2)
            //    {
            //        monthi.Income /= 1.05;
            //    }

            //    if (selectedIndex == 3)
            //    {
            //        monthi.Income /= 7.55;
            //    }
            //}

            //Próximo Mês
            MonthlyIncomeCalculus.Add(monthi);
        }

    }

    private void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)sender;
        selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

        //if (selectedIndex == 1)
        //{
        //    monthi.Income = monthi.Income;
        //}
        //if (selectedIndex == 2)
        //{
        //    monthi.Income /= 1.05;
        //}

        //if (selectedIndex == 3)
        //{
        //    monthi.Income /= 7.55;
        //}

    }

}
```